# Android button shape in selector doesn't work

Tags: android, button, shapes, cornerradius

I have a `button` and a `selector` that  must change `color`, `padding` and `corner radius`  of the `button`. I have no problems with changing the `color`, but  I can never see any changes with `padding` and `corner radius`.

`button_color.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@color/button_disabled" android:state_enabled="false">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle"
        android:padding="8dp">
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />

    </shape>
</item>
<item android:drawable="@color/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle"
        android:padding="8dp">
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />

    </shape>
</item>
<item android:drawable="@color/button_focused" android:state_focused="true">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle"
        android:padding="8dp">
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />

    </shape>
</item>
<item android:drawable="@color/colorAccent">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle"
        android:padding="8dp">
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

code  of the `button`:

```
    <LinearLayout>

    ....
    <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/add_to_fav"
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:background="@drawable/button_color"
    android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

I know some clumsy way to get the `padding`  - put it  into the layout, but 1) it would be "useless parent"; 2) I wouldn't get `corner radius`.

So what am I doing wrong so I have not `shape`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Padding, color and corners should be inside `shape`

So try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape>
            <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="2dp"
                     android:right="5dp" android:bottom="2dp" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="2dp"
                     android:right="5dp" android:bottom="2dp" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape>
            <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="2dp"
                     android:right="5dp" android:bottom="2dp" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="2dp"
                     android:right="5dp" android:bottom="2dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

This way all of them will work.

Comment: Indeed! It has changed the `corner radius`! But padding has left the same, so solve this through the `margin`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The `android:radius` value was probly just too small for the effect to be visible. The syntax for the `padding` on the other hand has to be changed like this:

```
<item android:drawable="@color/button_focused" android:state_focused="true">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="20dip" />
        <padding
            android:left="8dip"
            android:top="8dip"
            android:right="8dip"
            android:bottom="8dip" />

    </shape>
</item>
```

**Please note**: as stated in the [documentation for Shape Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape),

> Padding to apply to the containing View element (this pads the position of the View content, not the shape).